# How to reset a pagination to first page on filter change in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs

//How to reset a pagination to first page on filter change in ui-grid.

```
   $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged( $scope, function() {
                              var grid = this.grid;
                              //var fdata = grid.columns.field;
                              if(paginationOptions.pageNumber > 1){
                               // how to reset the pagination page to first page if pagenumber is greater then zero(0)
                              }
                            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to do this because if the user wants to go to the second page they will be sent back to the first page so why have pagination in the first place?  Anyway I have not tested this but it seems like you can use the seek function.

$scope.gridApi.pagination.seek(The page you want to go to);

In your case I think it would be

```
  $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged( $scope, function() {

                          if($scope.gridApi.pagination.getPage() > 1){
                              $scope.gridApi.pagination.seek(1);
                          }
                        });
```

I am not 100% on this because I have never used the pagination functionality of ui-grid or tested this code but I hope this helps.  Also if it does not work you should use your browsers developer tools and step through each line to see what is happening which will help you debug and get what you want.

use these links to get a better understanding of the functionality for ui-grid

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.pagination.api:PublicAPI

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2061